# How to map tree type relation in database mysql in hibernate

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hibernate, orm

I have the following scenario

`GroceryList` dpeneds upon `AgeGroup`

and `GroceryList` belongs to `Categories`

In my page I want to show like

```
Agegroup

----------Catgeory

------------------------List1
------------------------List2
```

Agegroup2

```
----------Catgeory2

------------------------List12
------------------------List22
```

I am confused should i have class AgeGroup relation with Category or not. Because if yes then it will be easy to navigate. But all categories will belong to all Agegroups

Comment: What is ur use case when you say easier to navigate ? Get Lists belong to a particular category and a particular AgeGroup ? I don't see how you need a all categories belong to all AgeGroups structure

Comment: The categories are fixed. But i want to show on the html page like tree structure. E,g i have  10 AgeGroups , Then i have 5 Categories. So on my Page i will first have CatgeoryName then all list under it and then secondCatgeoryName then all list under it. So the categories will be same acroos all AgeGroup Pages. This becomes problem for me to call Query GetListForCatgeory() as many times. Othwsie if i have categories in Agegroup then i can walk like `AgeGroup--Catgories--lists` from ORM point ofview

Comment: You can do something like this: "Select o From List o WHERE o.ageGroup.id = :ageGroupId and o.category.id = :categoryId"

Comment: Or just load all GetListByAgeGroup() for every AgeGroup page, and display the List by their list.category attribute.